# Shader optimisation by moving code outside main(){}

Tags: opengl, canvas, webgl, gpu

When writing shaders is the code outside the main function executed for every (vertex / fragment) or is it executed only once per draw call, thereby providing a benefit by pre calculating many values at the beginning of the draw.

For example will the following vertex shader perform better than the one below?

```
#attribute vec4 position;
#attribute vec2 texcoord;
// desc. Sprite description array items in order
// startCoord, endCoord, ununsed  , textScale,(unused,screenAspect),(alpha,scale),unused,tile
#uniform vec2 desc[8];   
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
varying float alpha;
const vec2 proj = vec2(-0.5, 0.5);

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
// Does the following code only run once per draw code.
// code common to all verts
float aspect = desc[4].y;
vec2 aspectV = vec2(1.0,aspect);
vec2 line   =  desc[1] - desc[0]; 
vec2 lineI  =  normalize(line / aspectV);
float len   =  length(line / aspectV) *2.0;
vec2 lineJ  =  lineI * desc[3].y * desc[5].y;
vec2 textX  =  vec2(len / desc[5].y / desc[3].x / 2.0, 1.0);
mat4 tMat   =  mat4(1);  // if I change this to include assigning the 
                         // vectors lineI and lineJ will this provide a 
                         // performance benefit.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

void main() {
   tMat[0][0] = lineI.x ;
   tMat[0][1] = lineI.y * aspect;
   tMat[1][0] = lineJ.y;
   tMat[1][1] = -lineJ.x * aspect;
   gl_Position  = (tMat * vec4(position.xy * vec2(len,2.0), position.zw)) +  vec4((desc[0] + proj) * 2.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   v_texcoord = texcoord * textX;
   alpha = desc[5].x;
}
```

All code inside main, is this slow?

```
#attribute vec4 position;
#attribute vec2 texcoord;
// desc. Sprite description array items in order
// startCoord, endCoord, ununsed  , textScale,(unused,screenAspect),(alpha,scale),unused,tile
#uniform vec2 desc[8];   
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
varying float alpha;
const vec2 proj = vec2(-0.5, 0.5);

void main() {
   float aspect = desc[4].y;
   vec2 aspectV =   vec2(1.0,aspect);
   vec2 line  = desc[1] - desc[0]; 
   vec2 lineI = normalize(line / aspectV);
   float len  = length(line / aspectV) *2.0;
   vec2 lineJ = lineI * desc[3].y * desc[5].y;
   vec2 textX = vec2(len / desc[5].y / desc[3].x / 2.0, 1.0);
   mat4 tMat  = mat4(1);  
   tMat[0][0] = lineI.x ;
   tMat[0][1] = lineI.y * aspect;
   tMat[1][0] = lineJ.y;
   tMat[1][1] = -lineJ.x * aspect;
   gl_Position  = (tMat * vec4(position.xy * vec2(len,2.0), position.zw)) +  vec4((desc[0] + proj) * 2.0, 0.0, 0.0) ;
   v_texcoord = texcoord * textX;
   alpha = desc[5].x;
}`
```

Comment: I'm not sure what language/framework you are using, but this are definitely no standard glsl shaders.

Comment: There is no benefit in doing so, [for more detail check out the answer on this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61257/glsl-declaring-global-variables-outside-of-the-main-function-scope)

Comment: @LJ Thanks for the link but it did not answer my question. I just want to know if code outside main is executed once per draw call or once per vertex/fragment (depending on the type)

Comment: It's executed once per iteration of the shader. In other words `gl.drawArrays(..., 6)` it's executed 6 times inside or out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to ignore the fact that `#attribute` and `#uniform` are not legal GLSL constructs. I'll pretend you were using actual legitimate GLSL.

Your question, essentially, is do you expect the call to `glUniform` to actually update the value of all of those global variables.

I would not expect such an optimization out of implementations. These kinds of optimization are difficult to do, because they involve the creation of implicit uniform values. And that can increase the number of *effective* uniforms a shader uses, possibly blowing past the legal uniform count.

If you want to ensure that these pre-calculations are done per-draw call, then *you* should do them and make the results a `uniform` you provide to the shader explicitly.

Comment: Its for webGL, Calculating the values outside the shaders is way to slow in ECMAScript. It is a shame I can not write to the uniforms from within the shader as that would provide a significant improvement especially for  fragment shaders. The # just a pre compile directive that generates the code to set Uniforms, Attributes,and more..

Comment: @Blindman67: "*The # just a pre compile directive that generates the code to set Uniforms, Attributes,and more..*" That not legitimate webGL-based GLSL either. There's nothing in [the WebGL specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0/) that suggest that this is valid syntax.

Comment: I am not concerned if the syntax conforms the any specification as long as it compiles, runs, and is optimal that is all that matters . We are free to extend any language if we see fit.

Comment: It doesn't compile `*** Error compiling shader: ERROR: 0:1: 'attribute' : invalid directive name ` If it's compiling for you either you're doing some string substitution or you're using a non WebGL spec conforming browser.

Comment: @Blindman67 "*Calculating the values outside the shaders is way to slow in ECMAScript*" uhm what ? Arithmetic operations in particular are quite close to native speeds  in modern javascript engines, if these few operations are bottlenecking your application in any way you may want to read up on writing performant javascript or create a question in regards to your performance issues.

Comment: @LJᛃ LOL Thanks for the advice, but I prefer off loading anything i can to a GPU rather than being "quite close to native". The way i see it is if you don't have performance issues then you are just not pushing the limits.

Comment: @Blindman67: "*I prefer off loading anything i can to a GPU rather than being "quite close to native*" That is a decidedly poor way to achieve high-performance code. The GPU is not fast just because it's the GPU. If you're rendering 100,000 vertices in a mesh, you'll get faster results by doing one-time computations on the CPU and uploading the results to the GPU than by making the GPU compute the exact same thing 100,000 times. Engines written in C++ do things that way; that's why they mostly deal in matrices and simple data structures. Why would JavaScript be any different?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I am not writing a 3D game, I am rendering 100,000 plus verts off which every 6 represents a unique translated, rotated, scaled, sheet referenced, FXed, sprite. Writing 8 32bit floats per sprite is all I can afford in terms of JS code, Just adding one sqrt for normalising a vector and it does not work and just the app logic is at the limits.  I appreciate all the advice, but I have no need for conventional techniques, there are no rewards in ordinary.

Comment: @Blindman67: "*I am rendering 100,000 plus verts off which every 6 represents a unique translated, rotated, scaled, sheet referenced, FXed, sprite.*" And yet, you're passing those 8 32-bit floats as *uniforms*, rather than per-vertex data. Which means that you're actually issuing tens of thousands of individual draw commands. That's where all your performance is going. Not in the math computations, but in issuing drawing commands. The "ordinary" solution to this is to readjust your data so that you render all of your sprites in a single draw.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I have no performance problem, I asked a question in regard to improving performance, it does not mean I have slow code, I am a full order of magnitude faster than the best 2D webGL lib, and I have spent a year picking apart every lib out there..I am at 25000 unique sprites per frame (60fps) on 6yr old  GT 330M card, peeking 400Mpix per frame (@ card's limit). I want more.